xsl 1.0 -Day drops 0 when adding one day to date
I have little to no experience with xsl and inherited this stylesheet. It's an ACH payment and payment date must be 1 day after creation date. Issue: When the day is 01-08, it drops the leading 0 and shows as 24062, instead of 240602. Also when it is last day of the month, instead of going to the next month 240601, it shows as 240532.
When I remove the +1 in the code, then the date shows as expected with the leading 0.
Here's how the date is set up. There's no template/ param... just below:
<xsl:value-of select="substring(PaymentInstructionInfo/InstructionCreationDate, 3, 2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(PaymentInstructionInfo/InstructionCreationDate, 6,2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(PaymentInstructionInfo/InstructionCreationDate, 9, 2) +1"/>


XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates and cannot perform date calculations. Find out which processor you are using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153), perhaps it supports some extension functions that can help. Otherwise see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412319/3016153 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693274/17153010. Or upgrade your processor to XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Well the reason the code doesn't roll over to the next month is because it makes no attempt to do so: 31 + 1 is 32, and no-one is telling the processor to do date arithmetic. Similarly the reason it doesn't display the day with a leading zero is because it makes no attempt to format it, so it gets the default format for an integer which will have no leading zeroes.
You could solve the formatting easily enough by using the format-number() function to force leading zeroes, but for the month roll-over you really need a date-and-time library. There's lots of date-and-time functionality in XSLT 2.0, and there's also an EXSLT date-and-time library supported by many XSLT 1.0 processors. But there's nothing that comes "out of the box" as standard XSLT 1.0.
You've inherited code that has some pretty fundamental bugs in it; if it has problems like this, then it is going to have lots of other problems too. You're not going to be able to sort it out without investing some time in learning XSLT.

Where can we find this EXSLT library please?

The specification of the EXSLT library can be found at https://exslt.github.io . However, just because the specification exists does not mean that the functions are necessarily implemented for any particular XSLT processor. There's some information about implementations on the EXSLT pages but it is probably out of date. You would be better off finding an XSLT 2.0+ processor.
